# GraphQL filter Contentful posts

Tags: arrays, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm trying to fetch posts like `category->post1, post2`, but some category has no post. So I want to skip/filter those categories. How can I do that?

Query example:

```
query MyQuery {
  allContentfulCategory(limit: 10, filter: {}) {
    edges {
      node {
        slug
        name
        blog_post {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxnLZ.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your GraphQL nodes are properly set, you just can:

```
query MyQuery {
  allContentfulCategory(limit: 10, filter: {blog_post: {slug: {ne: null}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        slug
        name
        blog_post {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `ne` (not equal) filter should do the trick.

Alternatively, you can filter directly using JavaScript code, since it's a `null` value, it can be easily removed from the `node` array with:

```
let filtered = data.allContentfulCategory.edges.node.filter(el => el.blog_post != null);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, please have a look at this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/eNBKeVL.png  
(I've tried {blog_post: {ne: null}}, it says blog_post doesn't have `ne`...)

Comment: In that case, filter for a null slug, like `allContentfulCategory(limit: 10, filter: {blog_post: {slug: {ne: null}}}) {`

Comment: Still no luck, blog_post has only one property is elemMatch, screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/0F8rnzw.png

Comment: and `elemMatch: {slug: {ne: null}}` has no effect here

Comment: What about directly `allContentfulCategory(limit: 10, filter: {slug: {ne: null}}) {` You have access to the `slug` according to https://i.imgur.com/eNBKeVL.png

Comment: this slug is category slug, it has nothing to do with `blog_post` and it will never be null. Here `category->blog_post` can be null or `category->blog_post->elemMatch->id,slug,etc`, So I need to filter when `category->blog_post` is null

Comment: Another workaround is to filter directly in the JS code, once the request and the fetching is done

Comment: yeah, now filtering via js. Thanks so much for your time :)